# Why do I see 'NOTICE' messages when I push my application using the PHP buildpack?

Tags: php, push, ibm-cloud

Every time I deploy my PHP application I see lots of these 'NOTICE' messages in my logs.

For example, when I run 'cf logs APPNAME'  I see:

> 2015-04-10T15:00:59.70+0100 [App/0] ERR [10-Apr-2015 14:00:59] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
>
> 2015-04-10T15:01:00.63+0100 [App/0] ERR [10-Apr-2015 14:00:59] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
>
> 2015-04-10T15:01:00.63+0100 [App/0] ERR [10-Apr-2015 14:00:59] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 93
>
> 2015-04-10T15:01:00.63+0100 [App/0] ERR [10-Apr-2015 14:00:59] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question you are asking?

Comment: @PeterSmith  Sorry, this is my first post.  The question I am asking is WHY do I get these NOTICE messages and HOW can I make them go away.  Should I have put it that way in the header of the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see in your logs is controlled by the value of the error_log parameter in the PHP buildpack, which defines the application's logging level.

By default, the value of the error_log parameter is **stderr notice**.

The following is an example of the default logging level configuration in the `nginx-defaults.conf` file of the PHP buildpack that is provided by Cloud Foundry.

```
daemon off;
error_log stderr notice;
pid @{HOME}/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
```

**NOTICE** messages are informational and usually do not an indicate a problem.
To stop the logging of these messages change the logging level from
**stderr notice**
to
**stderr error**
in the `nginx-defaults.conf` file of the buildpack.

For example:

```
daemon off;
error_log stderr error; 
pid @{HOME}/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
```

For more information on the buildpack, see [cloudfoundry/php-buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/ff71ea41d00c1226d339e83cf2c7d6dda6c590ef/defaults/config/nginx/1.5.x/nginx-defaults.conf).

For more information about how to change the default logging configuration, see [error_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log).

Answer (score 1):

These messages are safe to ignore. The buildpack is sending these notice messages to stderr. I will look to see if this can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` in your script, else modify it in your php.ini